# Getting error while running app over https using Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I need to test my APP over `https` but here I am getting the below error while running my App using Python.

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection

127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I am making an app using Python and Django and wanted to run over the `https`. My `settings.py` is given below.

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for carClinic project.
"""

import os

""" Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...) """
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

""" SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret! """
SECRET_KEY = 'e8rq8bj5=w6cyiw&37s2kdys&$mg9m8agh@-%c6_+-jpu-21y='

""" SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! """
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


""" Application definition """

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bookingservice'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'carClinic.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'carClinic.wsgi.application'


""" Database """

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


""" Password validation """

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


""" Internationalization """

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

""" Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images) """

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: How are you running your app?

Comment: As @DanielRoseman suggests, the issue may be in the front server, and not in Django project. If the front server (apache, nginx,  ...) what's the result when you try to get a static file with your browser (image or CSS file) ? What does the server (not Django) error log show for this request ?

Comment: Actually I am running in localhost `https://127.0.0.1:8000/` by running the command `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: And why did you expect that to work? Serving a site via HTTPS requires all sorts of infrastructure - eg certificates - that is not provided by the development server. You need a real webserver for this.

Comment: I have Apache in my system Can you guide me how to do this ?

Comment: Please update your post and provide the Apache virtualhost config for this site.

Answer (score 0):

To connect over HTTPS you need a valid SSL certificate on the server. From the error message it looks like you're connecting to a server on your local computer, and while you could get a certificate for that, it probably isn't worth the trouble. There is really no reason to test HTTPS on a local computer if you are planning on deploying to a server, as you'll have to set up SSL again on the server, and even if it works on your computer, it might not work on the server.

I recommend that you deploy the app to a server (you'll need a webserver like apache or nginx for that), and then set up a free [Let's Encrypt certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/). Then you'll be able to connect over HTTPS.

If you really need to do this on you local computer, you must first get a fixed public IP-address, which you'll have to get from your ISP. If you use the IP-address you have now it will probably change in a few days or so, and then you'll have to get a new certificate.